How to type a Python function with optional arguments according to a literal type?
Let's say I want to implement a router function that would take a name as argument and optionally a data argument.
For example the function would be called using:
route("main")

to go to the main screen or
route("edit", item.id)

to go to the item edition screen.
This code works but I don't have any type hinting and so no errors are raised from typecheckers:
from typing import Literal

def route(name: Literal["main", "edit"], *args) -> None:
    match name:
        case "main":
            print("Main screen")
        case "edit":
            if not args:
                raise ValueError("No item id provided for editing.")
            print(f"Editing item id: {args[0]}")
        case _:
            raise ValueError(f"Invalid route name: {name}")

route("main") # Main screen
route("edit", 12) # Editing item id: 12
route("edit")  # Raises ValueError

Fiddle
I tried using TypeGuards or TypeIs, but if I understand well PEP 647 and PEP 647 they would work in the opposite way — they narrow the type inside the function but don't affect the function signature.

@overloading may be an option…?

Is your function really def route(name: Literal["main","edit"], id: int|None=None), or do you expect args to receive other arguments?

@deceze Yes, something like this could work : https://python-fiddle.com/saved/tutYxFqZTIqc44G8HW5V but it looks a bit busy doesn't it ?

@larsks ideally it would be def route(name: Literal["main","edit", "someaction"], id: int| SomeObject | None=None) but I'm not sure of what it would imply ?

Please don't put answers in the question - if that works post an answer, if it doesn't update the question fully to ask about the new problem.

Keep in mind that you should probably just have separate functions route_main and route_edit.

Sorry @jonsharpe, my bad.

These should probably be two separate functions that don't require a literal first argument at all.
def route_main() -> None:
    print("Main screen")


def route_edit(id: int) -> None:
    print(f"Editing item id: {id}")


route_main()  # Main screen
route_edit(12)  # Editing item id: 12
route_edit()  # Raises TypeError, but also fails static type checking

Whatever logic you have that decides which literal argument to pass to route can also be used to decide which of the two functions above to call.

A solution suggested by @deceze would be the use of @overloads:
from typing import overload, Union, Literal

class Router:
    @overload
    def route(self, name: Literal["main"]) -> None:
        ...

    @overload
    def route(self, name: Literal["edit"], id: int) -> None:
        ...

    def route(self, name: Literal["main"] | Literal["edit"], id: int | None = None) -> None:
        if name == "main":
            print("main")
        if name == "edit":
            if not id:
                print( "error")
            print(id)

# Usage
router = Router()
router.route("main")
router.route("edit", 5)
router.route("edit") # Linter error
router.route("main", 6) # Linter error

I personally think it looks a bit busy and would not scale well.
Fiddle

Perfect solution, but you don't need an enclosing Router class.

For some reason mypy doesn't like it if I dont add those methods to a class:
main.py:20: error: No overload variant of "route" matches argument type "str"  [call-overload]

You probably forgot to remove self var. This caused the same warning on my side until I fixed it.
